# Service Fabric StatelessService cannot access StatefulService within the same cluster

Tags: service-fabric-stateful, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to connect to a stateful service from a Web Controller within the same cluster.

The services deployed fine and they look healthy with no issues on the local cluster.

The address used is also correct (it matches also the Cluster Manager's def), but when it comes to call this simple method in the **ValuesController**:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{

// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<NodeKey>> GetAll()
{
    var nodeKeyClient = ServiceProxy.Create<ISharedKeysService>(new Uri("fabric:/ReliableCollections/SharedKeys"), new ServicePartitionKey(1), TargetReplicaSelector.PrimaryReplica);
    var keys = nodeKeyClient.GetAllNodeKeys().Result;
    return new ActionResult<IEnumerable<NodeKey>>(keys);
}
```

I get an exception:

> FabricException: The primary or stateless instance for the partition
>   'd74703d1-d74f-49cc-9457-3ab643063ac4' has invalid address, this means
>   that right address from the replica/instance is not registered in the
>   system.

**SharedKeys** is defined as follow:

```
internal sealed class SharedKeys : StatefulService,ISharedKeysService
{
    public SharedKeys(StatefulServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
    { }

    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
    {
        return new[] { new ServiceReplicaListener(context => this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(context)) };
    }
```

I tried restarting the cluster, changing the partition number, etc. 
It does work with stateless services though.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Microsoft.ServiceFabric version is **6.3.187**

Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting is **3.2.187**

The service manifest has the following endpoint defined :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest Name="SharedKeysPkg"
                 Version="1.0.0"
                ...

  <Resources>
    <Endpoints>
       <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" />
       <Endpoint Name="ReplicatorEndpoint" />
    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
</ServiceManifest>
```

Comment: Do you have the remoting endpoint defined in your (stateful) service manifest?

Comment: Thank you, I have added that bit of information. I am struggling a bit because I considered adding endpoint information the same way WCF works, but I am not sure how?

Comment: Can you add information about partitioning schema used by stateful service?